# Pandas: replace values in column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have df and I want to replace values there

```
df = pd.read_csv('visits_april.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('participants.csv')`

url, date
aliexpress.com/payment/payment-result.htm...  2016-04-30 22:57:41   
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-30 23:05:21   
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-30 23:05:33   
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-30 23:11:37   
aliexpress.com/payment/payment-result.htm...  2016-04-30 23:12:07   
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-30 23:15:31   
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-30 23:15:37   
aliexpress.com/payment/payment-result.htm...  2016-04-30 23:16:13   
            kupivip.ru/shop/checkout/confirmation  2016-04-30 23:18:15
```

if string from `df` contain string from `df2` I want to replace it to string from `df2`

```
visits
aliexpress.com
ozon.ru
wildberries.ru
lamoda.ru
mvideo.ru
eldorado.ru
ulmart.ru
ebay.com
kupivip.ru
```

Desire output

```
url
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
aliexpress.com
kupivip.ru
```

I try `df[df['url'].isin(df2['visits'])]` but it return `Empty DataFrame`.

Comment: Could you please add the code for creating the panda dataframe, so we do not have to recreate it manually, to test possible solutions ?

Comment: @HolyDanna I read it from file file `pd.read_csv('namefile.csv')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) joined list with `|` (regex `or`) from column `visits` by [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
L = df2.visits.tolist()
print (L)
['aliexpress.com', 'ozon.ru', 'wildberries.ru', 'lamoda.ru', 
'mvideo.ru', 'eldorado.ru', 'ulmart.ru', 'ebay.com', 'kupivip.ru']

print (df.url.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(L) + ')', expand=False))
0    aliexpress.com
1    aliexpress.com
2    aliexpress.com
3    aliexpress.com
4    aliexpress.com
5    aliexpress.com
6    aliexpress.com
7    aliexpress.com
8        kupivip.ru
Name: url, dtype: object
```

Comment: It replace it, but I have other columns in this `df` and they are dissapearing

Comment: Sorry, then you need `df['url'] = df.url.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(L) + ')', expand=False)`